# Debugger not working properly after memcpy

Tags: c

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    double x;
    foo(&x);
    // ...
}


foo(double *p){
    char bytes[8];
    bytes[0]=62;
    bytes[1]=-120;
    bytes[2]=41;
    bytes[3]=23;
    bytes[4]=-16;
    bytes[5]=-57;
    bytes[6]=47;
    bytes[7]=-40;
    // bytes = 00111110 10001000 00101001 00010111 11110000 11000111 00101111 11011000
    memcpy(p,bytes,sizeof(double));
    // (1)
}
```

After `memcpy` I would expect to find those bits inside x, but at line of code (1) in debugger I have

```
*p = Binary: 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
     Hex: 0x8000000000000000
```

However by printing the value with `fprintf(stderr,"%x",*p);` I get the value `1729883e`.

Comment: You need to show us where `bytes` is populated.

Comment: also u didn't assign any initial value

Comment: Please, construct a minimal working example that shows the behaviour you're interested in. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I think, main error in your `//stuff ...`

Comment: where I wrote //stuff I'm copying those bits inside bytes[8]. After that bytes contains those bits. I checked it with debugger.

Comment: @Eddy_Em I cannot see any error there.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the bits of the double correctly?

Comment: @BWG: debugger says: *p = Details: -6.2611772209811927e+116, Hex: 0x8000000000000000, Binary:1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem on your toolchain would be extremely helpful! For potential answerers as well as for you to boil it down. So far I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, and I seriously doubt that `memcpy()` from your toolchain has a bug.

Comment: @HAL9000: It looks like the debugger is converting the value to an integer type to display the hex and binary values; so the problem is with your debugger, not your code. Try displaying the memory at `p`.

Comment: It could be debugger error or debugger being out of sync. Try writing a "reverse" debug function, which prints the bytes of double as hex dump.

Comment: Works fine here: http://ideone.com/jaSlR1

Comment: @MikeSeymour I added a printf %f and the result equals to -6.2611772209811927e+116, which may be correct. However I cannot understand why bits in binary representation are not corresponding to the bits of bytes.

Comment: @HAL9000: It looks like the debugger is converting the value to an integer type to display the hex and binary values; so the problem is with your debugger, not your code. Try displaying the memory at `p`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I did it with printf. The Hex value printed is 1729883e, while debugger shows 8000000000000000. One can no longer trust debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some mods to get this to run and it did in fact populate x:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

bar(){
    double x;
    foo(&x);
    printf("%f\n", x);
}

foo(double *p){
    char bytes[8];
    bytes[0]=-62;
    bytes[1]=-120;
    bytes[2]=41;
    bytes[3]=23;
    bytes[4]=-16;
    bytes[5]=-57;
    bytes[6]=47;
    bytes[7]=-40;
    memcpy(p,bytes,sizeof(double));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    bar();
}
```

Output is: -626117722098128509564427792535309566746344523980579928553066490382037451337019090855228509979567689660741872330473472.000000

If this is not working for you, the problem is likely either in the rest of the code, or the debugger setup.

Comment: That value is also the value I see in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foo(double *p){
  unsigned char * chr;
  bytes[0]=62;
  bytes[1]=-120;
  bytes[2]=41;
  bytes[3]=23;
  bytes[4]=-16;
  bytes[5]=-57;
  bytes[6]=47;
  bytes[7]=-40;
  memcpy(p,bytes,sizeof(double));
  // (1)

  chr = (unsigned char *)p;

  printf("%x", *chr);
}
```

You get the correct value 62.